# Main Queue Async vs. Default Queue Async Explanation

Tags: ios, xcode, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I just watched this [raywenderlich.com video](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3648-ios-concurrency-with-gcd-and-operations/lessons/2) and took [this screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/3pWLdVt) of the code in question (@ 22:30).

I'm wondering how `mainQueue.async` finished after `defaultQueue.async` despite being put on what I thought was a higher priority queue (defaulting to `userInteractive` or `userInitiated`, but regardless higher than `default`, right?). I watched the entire video and felt like I had a great grasp on everything until seeing that. Would anyone please be able to explain? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough of the code in the screen shot to really see what's going on, but I think the issue is this:

The main queue is special; unlike all other dispatch queues, blocks added to the main queue get dispatched by the application's main run loop. All other dispatch queues execute blocks on any available thread.

So while a block you queue to run in the background will start almost immediately, anything you queue to run on the main thread has to wait until the main run loop cycles, and must wait its turn alongside timers, user input events, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those few lines of code are actually pretty much everything that affect those print lines :( I guess I was under the assumption that the main thread would have put it on a background thread (of higher priority too) before the code even reaches the second code block which gets added to the default queue.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never try to second guess when tasks will run. There are just too many variables (number of CPU cores, how busy the system is, other queued blocks, I/O blocking, the debugger, ...). If it's important to know or control, use semaphores or dispatch groups to impose an order. Otherwise, there are *zero* guarantees... :)